# Google spreadsheet script time limit of execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, time-limiting

I've written gs script to clear data from all cells in sheets. Spreadsheet has a lot of sheets (about 200) and I get error of time limit execution. Maybe somebody have ideas how to resolve this issue. Here example of my code.

```
function cleanAllOld() {

  var sheetsName = new Array();
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/link");
  var sheets = destination.getSheets();

  for (var k = 0; k < sheets.length; k++) {

    sheetsName.push([sheets[k].getName()]);

    for (var p = 0; p < sheetsName.length; p++) {
      var sheet = destination.getSheetByName(sheetsName[p]);
      if (sheet === null) {} else {
        sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get all the part of your code, but  I think he's too complicated for nothing. Here's is a sample which work:

```
function AllDelete() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/link");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var i = 0;

  for(i in sheets){

    sheets[i].clearContents();

  }

}
```

Edit: Max is fast and is right, the getDataRange() method is using a lot of ressources

Comment: I've got error "TypeError: Cannot find function clearContent in object Sheet." without `getDataRange()` . With it script works properly. Thank you.

Comment: My bad, there is a 's' missing in my sample. Look at the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is geting data range.

Try replace this

`sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();`

by this:

`sheet.clearContents();`